# Stacked metallized film caps -- what's the "outside" foil?

Tags: capacitor

One piece of advice that gets tossed around when low noise analog design is discussed is that the outside foil of a metallized film cap should be connected to AC/RF ground, or to whichever circuit node is closer to AC/RF ground, to basically act as a noise shield of sorts.  This is great for wound metallized film capacitors, where there is an "outside foil" to talk about.

However, almost all SMT film caps use a *stacked* structure similar to a MLCC -- see [this datasheet](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDI0000/ABD0000C173.pdf) for an example.  If you were using these capacitors in a low-noise or otherwise sensitive design, does it still matter which end is connected to the node nearer AC/RF ground?

Comment: I would say yes, if the PCB absorbs some RF passing through it.

Answer (score 2):

I would think so, particularly if there are traces passing under an SMT capacitor.

The fly in the ointment is that few manufacturers specify which end is which on the datasheet so you may have trouble getting the assembly right. [Panasonic](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDI0000/DMI0000COL24.pdf) 'sort-of' indicates a direction on their datasheet (unless it loses something in the translation), but it's not really unambiguously tied to orientation of the markings or orientation in the tape (via the packaging specifications), that I can see anyway.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I recently bought a reel of X7R caps with orientation markings (in a plastic case), this might explain that? Couldn't find this info on the datasheet. p.s.: that mouse cursor on the image got me confused for a sec. :P

Comment: I think I'll stick with keeping a keepout or a ground plane under critical caps.

Comment: Westley...I've never seen that.  What part did you buy?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have more flexibility if you use large capacitors to create quiet zones
in their shadows for the smaller components and foil traces.

I used this "mechanical engineering" trick at 4.5MHz in a NTSC FM sound demodulator circuit, where lots of components had to go into 2 square cm of board area. I used the large vertical-mount VDD electrolytics to shield the FM center frequency trimmer. The trimmer datasheet showed which part of the half-moon plate went with which lead, and I grounded that top lead. Goal was to prevent oscillation of NE604 FM-demod; we succeeded, with lots of capture-the-Efield-lines thinking.